# How to Make Desktop Entry for AptanaStudio3.sh

Tags: .desktop, aptana-studio

Whenever I try to run this command

```bsh
sh /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh
```

for the Aptana Studio 3 from root directory it shows that

```bsh
/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh: 3: /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh: ./AptanaStudio3: not found
```

but when i go to the directory it is executed easily.

Since I made shortcut for the given file and it shows

> **there was error launching the application**
>   [image]
>   and so i think the error as in the above command could be the reason for this.
>   If There is something else please let me know.

Code For Desktop Entry

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Aptana Studio 3
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
Comment=Aptana Strudio 3 Integrated Development Environment
Exec=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh
TryExec=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh
Icon=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AS3.png
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass="Aptana Studio 3"
Terminal=true
Type=Application
MimeType=text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/x-javascript;application/x-php;application/x-java;text/x-javascript;text/html;text/plain
Categories=GNOME;Development;IDE;
```

So I need your help to figure this and make a working desktop entry for this program

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? Do you mean when your current working directory is /root or when you are logged in as root it will not work? And when you `cd` to the directory and run `AptanaStudio3.sh ` it does run? I think that's what you mean. Are you logged in root? Do you need to be? How did you log in root? I may be able to better answer your question with some clarity.

Comment: ohk.....I one terminal and then simply type the command i.e. sh ./opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh 
Then It Shows me the error no such file or Directory all these commands are without sudo..
Secondly when change directory to the folder and then run ./AptanaStudio3.sh it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh` script.

```
sudo gedit /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.sh
```

There should be the line (apparently, the 3rd) which actually launches Aptana Studio. Change it to `/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3`. The reason is there should be [*absolute path*, not *relative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).

Comment: Please clarify. What does it show in the output?

Comment: ./opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3: No such file or directory

Comment: Notice the dot before `/opt`. It means that this path is still relative and starts in the current directory. To make path absolute, just remove the dot.

Comment: ohk....thanx it working....fine..and also thanx for letting me know the this relative and absolute path system

Comment: If you want to know more, visit the link I just added.

Comment: Sure and thanx..again..